# RevTeX, problem with comma in the addresses

Tags: revtex, affiliation

I'm using revtex 4.2 (with overleaf) and I'd like to writes commas in the adresses.

For instance in :

```
\documentclass[sor,jor,amsmath,amssymb,reprint,]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
\title[Sample title]{Title}
\author{A. Author}
\affiliation{Authors' institution and/or address}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

If I write commas in affiliation, it writes in the next line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[sor,jor,amsmath,amssymb,reprint,]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
\title[Sample title]{Title}
\author{A. Author}
\affiliation{Authors' institution and/or address\char`,{} next part}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's another way

```
\documentclass[sor,jor,amsmath,amssymb,reprint,]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
\title[Sample title]{Title}
\author{A. Author}
\let\comma,
\affiliation{Authors' institution and/or address\comma{} next part}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

To deactivate commas inside `\affiliation`:

```
\def\cat@comma@active{\catcode`\,12}%
```

Note that `\cat@comma@active` is only used inside `\affiliation`, so redefining it will not cause problems in other places.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[sor,jor,amsmath,amssymb,reprint,]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{bm}
\makeatletter
\def\cat@comma@active{\catcode`\,12}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \title[Sample title]{Title}
    \author{A. Author}
    \affiliation{Authors' institution, and/or address\\ 
        Another institution}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]